# Which R-squared value to report while using a fixed effects model - within, between or overall?

Tags: regression, stata, r-squared, fixed-effects-model

I am using a fixed effects model with household fixed effects. I just added a year dummy for year fixed effects. Here below is the Stata result screenshot from running the regression. In the regression results table, should I report R-squared as 0.2030 (within) or 0.0368 (overall)?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All three of these values provide some insight into your model, so you may need to report all three, but the within value is typically of main interest, as fixed-effects is known as the within estimator.  At least in Stata, it comes from OLS-estimated mean-deviated model:

$$
\left ( y_{it} - \bar{y_{i}} \right ) = \left ( x_{it} - \bar{x_{i}} \right )\boldsymbol{\beta } + \left ( \epsilon _{it} - \bar{\epsilon _{i}} \right )
$$

The definition of each of R-squared value is below:

- Within: How much of the variation in the dependent variable **within** household units is captured by your model (i.e., how well do your explanatory variables account for changes in DV within each of the households over time).  As I said above, in Stata it comes from the OLS-estimated mean-deviated model and is calculated as squared correlation between actual and predicted values of DV (which, in OLS case, is equal to the the ratio of their variances - the formal definition of R-squared).
- Between: How much of the variation in the dependent variable **between** household units is captured by your model (i.e., how well do your explanatory variables account for differences in DV between households).
- Overall: weighted average of the two

More detailed information (calculation of each one) can be obtained from the Stata manual: https://www.stata.com/manuals13/xtxtreg.pdf

Also, if you don't already know, if you are using `xtreg, fe` for your estimation, the within R-squared is obtained in a manner that assumes that groups (households, in your case) are fixed quantities, so their effects are removed from the model.  There is also `areg` procedure that estimates coefficients for each dummy variable for your groups.  More information can be found at:

https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/areg-versus-xtreg-fe

https://kb.iu.edu/auur

https://dss.princeton.edu/training/Panel101.pdf

Comment: Very helpful (+1). The latest version of the Stata manual entry (version 15 at the time of writing) is https://www.stata.com/manuals/xtxtreg.pdf It seems to be an artefact of Google that Stata 13 manual entries are often suggested in a search. I doubt that there is any substantial difference in this case.